# Getting an error when I am trying to use Java Spring Forms and Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am trying to use spring forms and spring security to create a simple login form but I am getting an error.

login.jsp :

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="resources/css/normalize.css"/>"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="resources/css/main.css"/>"/>

    <script src="<c:url value="resources/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"/>"></script>
    <script src="<c:url value="resources/js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"/>"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="resources/css/bootstrap.css"/>"/>

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="resources/css/jumbotron.css"/>"/>
</head>

<body>

<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<p class="chromeframe">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> or <a href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?redirect=true">activate Google Chrome Frame</a> to improve your experience.</p>
<![endif]-->

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" method="post" action="/j_spring_security_check">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" class="form-control" name="j_username" id="j_username">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" name="j_password" id="j_password">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Login</button>
            </form>
            <p class="text-danger">${message}</p>
        </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <p>This is a template for a simple marketing or informational website. It includes a large callout called the hero unit and three supporting pieces of content. Use it as a starting point to create something more unique.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <!-- Example row of columns -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <h2>Heading</h2>
            <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <h2>Heading</h2>
            <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <h2>Heading</h2>
            <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <hr>

    <footer>
        <p>&copy; Company 2013 - The time on server is ${serverTime}</p>
    </footer>
</div> <!-- /container -->

<script src="<c:url value="resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"/>"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml,
        /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Spring Security Configuration-->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>



</web-app>
```

servlet-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springapp.controllers"/>
</beans>
```

spring-security.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <security:http pattern="/resources" security="none"/>

    <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/denied" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/user" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>

        <security:form-login login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login/failure" default-target-url="/"/>

        <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/denied"/>

        <security:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/logout/sucess" logout-url="/logout"/>
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service>
                <security:user name="admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" password="admin"/>
                <security:user name="user" authorities="ROLE_USER" password="user"/>
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>



</beans>
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.springapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringMvc1</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringMvc1</name>

    <properties>
        <org.springframework-version>3.2.4.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.7.3</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.7.5</org.slf4j-version>
        <org.springsecurity-version>3.1.4.RELEASE</org.springsecurity-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springsecurity-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springsecurity-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springsecurity-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySql Connector -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.26</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>SpringMvc1</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The error I am getting is the following : http://pastebin.com/3ek1Ys1L
(If I remove the two (form and spring prefix) taglibs from the top of the login page, it loads without errors)

[image: Image of deployed directory]

Comment: Open up the `spring-mvc` jar downloaded by maven. Check in `META-INF` if there's a `spring-form.tld` file and if that file has a `uri` element with value `http://www.springframework.org/tags/form`

Comment: `find . -iname spring-mvc.*` inside project directory returns nothing.Where exactly does this jar resides?

Comment: It's not called `spring-mvc`. The jar should be in your maven repository. By default, I believe that it's installed in `/yourhome/.m2`.

Comment: I've found the .m2 directory but there is no jar starting with spring-mvc there.Can you be more specific about the jar we are looking for?

Comment: It's either `.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\3.2.4.RELEASE\spring-webmvc-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar` or `.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\3.2.4.RELEASE\spring-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar`

Comment: I've found this element in the spring-form.tld file in spring-webmvc directory.The spring-web directory does not contain such a file.

Comment: That's where it should be. I would try cleaning your app and rebuilding.

Comment: You mean clean the app using maven from the command line?

Comment: That and the deployment. Like delete your current one and reinstall.

Comment: I've run a mvn clean inside project folder, it builds succefully with only a maven-surefire-plugin missing error but then when I run it again I get the same exact 500 error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39213/discussion-between-skiabox-and-sotirios-delimanolis)

Comment: I've added an image of the war deployed directory.

Comment: I've installed the newer tomcat 7.0.42 tomcat version and I simply copied the war file inside webapps directory.Tomcat then deploys the application automaticallly, and I can click to it and run it!

Comment: Which version were you using before?

Comment: As I was suspecting it also runs from inside IntelliJ Idea!I was using tomcat 7.0.35

Comment: I'm surprised, not much difference between the two.

Comment: What can I say...maybe the fresh installation has proper and intact settings.

Comment: Glad you got it to work!